# MySQL reorganize partitions with subpartitions

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table partitioned by year and sub-partitioned by month.
Here the creation statement.

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `created_at` date NOT NULL,
 `language` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`created_at`),
 KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1724800187 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (YEAR(created_at))
SUBPARTITION BY HASH ( MONTH(created_at))
SUBPARTITIONS 12
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2016) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2017) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

I want to reorganize partitions so that p2 will contains only 2018 data and new partitions (p3, p4 and p5) will contains future years data.

Is it correct, in this case, to perform a "reorganize partition" using the following statement?

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` REORGANIZE PARTITION `p2` INTO 
( 
  PARTITION `p2` VALUES LESS THAN (2018) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
  PARTITION `p3` VALUES LESS THAN (2019) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION `p4` VALUES LESS THAN (2020) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION `p5` VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE 
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to prepare the partitions for future data and, above all, I would like to understand if my solution is correct. Why do you ask me that?

Comment: There are some really great articles on partitioning out there, which explain why your approach might not be the best

Comment: Could you explain what solution I should take?